# What is the maximum line length a browser can render?

Tags: javascript

... plotted over time on the x axis and length on the y-axis to be really useful.

I've heard/read that some JavaScript minifiers add in return characters b.c. some browsers have a maximum line length that can be rendered.  What is it for modern browsers? FF, IE, Safari, and Chrome.  Any will suffice as a starting point.

I've also heard that breaking the lines up is for firewalls and proxies which have a maximum length that can be parsed.  Google closure puts this at around 500 lines.

But this question regards the browsers capabilities.

Here is a link to information that puts the browser issue, at around 32K.

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

**Related**

[SO Post regarding proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018049/why-does-googles-closure-compiler-leave-a-few-unnecessary-spaces-or-line-breaks)

There is definitely some consistency lacking in what minifiers think this needs to be set to.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answers may be relevant for only a short period of time. Browsers change at a fairly rapid pace, so what is modern at the time the question is asked may not be modern a few months from now when someone stumbles on this question. 

Comment: updated question for a non-time based answer.